# How to handle "I attack" during a peaceful narrative

Tags: dnd-5e, initiative, surprise

Abdullah, Ben, and Caroline are talking to a Drow that they know may prove hostile.     Abdullah and Ben are fine with seeing how the conversation goes, but Caroline doesn't want to risk it.  As the conversation proceeds, she interrupts the Drow (being narrated by me, the DM) by saying "I attack with my crossbow."

Combat has clearly started, but how specifically?

1. I imagine since the Drow was looking right at Caroline when she
   pulled the crossbow, they are not Surprised.  Is this correct?
2. How should initiative be handled?  Should they all roll and turn
   order be established that way, or should Caroline be assumed to be
   at the top of the order, and have Abdullah, Ben, and the Drow roll
   to determine the rest of the order?

Comment: Related: [How does attacking during a conversation affect initiative?](/questions/154283), [Should players get a surprise attack by interrupting a villain's speech?](/questions/76829)